# SQLite no such column error to select column based on selected column

Tags: sql, sqlite

I found this weird in SQLite, if I simply select a column based on previously selected columns. The following SQL statement:

```
SELECT Column1 AS C1, C1 || 'something' AS C2 FROM Table1;
```

Will return an error in SQLite:

> No such column C1

But it goes on without an error in Access.

Wondering how do I do a similar selection in SQLite? Basically I want to do this in a single `SELECT` instead of two `SELECT`.

Comment: This is not weird.  This is how SQL works.  It is how SQLite works.  In general, you need to repeat the expression or use a subquery to use an alias defined in a `select`.

Comment: so could you suggest me a sql statement that achieves the above using subquery? Thank you!

Comment: you could just do Column1 || something instead of c1 because that is the only issue there

Comment: Select Column1 AS C1, Column1 || 'something' AS C2 from Table1;

Comment: I'm using Column1 as an example, I'm actually using some quite complicated criteria to determine C1, then I want to use C1 as a criterion to determine C2.

Comment: This behaviour is based on Standard SQL, only Access and Teradata allow using an alias outside of ORDER BY. You need to repeat the calculation or use a Derived Table.

Answer (score 1):

The canonical way is:

```
Select C1, C1 || 'something' AS C2
from (select column1 as c1, t1.*
      from Table1 t1
     ) t1
```

Comment: Could you please briefly explain this query? I tired and it says no such table t1. Thank you.